# Systems of partial difference equations

Tags: finite-differences, recurrence-relations

I would like to ask, if any general method of solving systems of partial difference (not differential) equations is known, at least for some classes of systems. For instance, for *ordinary* difference equations, there is a general method of solving homogenous systems of first-order linear O$\Delta$E's with constant coefficients. Can it be extended to P$\Delta$E's? Or, equivalently, is there any general method of solving *infinite* homogenous systems of first-order linear O$\Delta$E's with constant coefficients?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1954-076-01/S0002-9947-1954-0059635-7/S0002-9947-1954-0059635-7.pdf